# Disc image Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, file-permissions

I've tried to download a disc image via torrent and now I can't delete it.

Every time I click delete I can tell from my task manager that it opens the file which appears to be why I can not delete it.

How can I force delete this file? Since it is a disc image will I have to eject it somehow? Etc.

It worries me to have such a file on my computer.

(it's an ISO-file)

Comment: Your question is not clear. When you attempt to delete it what happens exactly?   Unless you mounted the image you should be able to delete the file.

Comment: If it's mounted, right-clicking the drive letter and ejecting should allow you to delete the ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting the computer, usually easiest way to free up any file locks.

Comment: Windows 8 has the ability to mount an ISO file.  If the file is mounted a restart won't unmount the file.

Answer (score 0):

enter that disc image file, in Windows 10, go to "Manage" tab of folder, "Eject" the image disc. the folder will be closed automatically, then  go to that file, buy don't enter to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hwoever there are a couple of things: The question asked about Windows 8; and I'm not sure what you mean by "enter that disc image file... but don't enter to the file"- can you clarify?